# How to fold "#if ... #endif", but skip "{" in between?

Tags: vim

I add this line to `~/.vimrc` to fold C macro `#if` ... `#endif`:

```
au FileType h,c,cpp syn region zhouzmFoldIf start="^\s*#if" end="^\s*#endif" fold transparent extend
```

It works well most of the time. But if there is a `{` in between, it can't fold correctly.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

[In this vim_use thread](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/49ed223185b6cb07), the problem is discussed. Ben Fritz posted the following solution.

```
" fold #if...#else...#endif constructs
syn region IfFoldContainer
    \ start="^\s*#\s*if\(n\?def\)\?\>"
    \ end="#\s*endif\>"
    \ skip=+"\%(\\"\|[^"]\)\{-}\\\@<!"\|'[^']\{-}'\|'\\''\|//.*+
    \ transparent
    \ keepend extend
    \ containedin=NONE
    \ contains=SynFoldIf,SynFoldElif,SynFoldElse
syn region SynFoldIf
    \ start="^\s*#\s*if\(n\?def\)\?\>"
    \ end="^\s*#\s*el\(se\|if\)\>"ms=s-1,me=s-1
    \ skip=+"\%(\\"\|[^"]\)\{-}\\\@<!"\|'[^']\{-}'\|'\\''\|//.*+
    \ fold transparent
    \ keepend
    \ contained
    \ nextgroup=SynFoldElif,SynFoldElse
    \ contains=TOP
syn region SynFoldElif
    \ start="^\s*#\s*elif\>"
    \ end="^\s*#\s*el\(se\|if\)\>"ms=s-1,me=s-1
    \ skip=+"\%(\\"\|[^"]\)\{-}\\\@<!"\|'[^']\{-}'\|'\\''\|//.*+
    \ fold transparent
    \ keepend
    \ contained
    \ nextgroup=SynFoldElse
    \ contains=TOP
syn region SynFoldElse
    \ start="^\s*#\s*else\>"
    \ end="^\s*#\s*endif\>"
    \ skip=+"\%(\\"\|[^"]\)\{-}\\\@<!"\|'[^']\{-}'\|'\\''\|//.*+
    \ fold transparent
    \ keepend
    \ contained
    \ contains=TOP
```